# Import class Java

Tags: java

I realize this question has probably been asked many times, but I can't find any answer that works for me.

I'm learning the basics of Java coding from a manual on coding physics. The manual includes source code for plotting data:

https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/javacourse/Plot.java.txt

I've saved it as Plot.java, and compiled it in the folder I'm working in. The manual tells me to use the following code:

```
Plot myPlot = new Plot("Plot of y vs. x",0,10,1,-1.5,1.5,0.5);
```

But when I try to compile the code I get an error that says the Plot symbol can't be found.

So how do I use the Plot class in my code? Do I import it or something? If so, how?

Edit:

Here is the code of the program:

```
package rangeplot;

class RangePlot {


RangePlot(double speed) {
    Plot myPlot = new Plot("range vs angle",
    0,90,1,0,45,1);


    myPlot.addPoint(angle,range);
    }
}
```

The exact error message:

```
RangePlot.java:7: error: cannot find symbol

Plot myPlot = new Plot("range vs angle",
^

symbol: class Plot
location: class RangePlot
```

I've tried:

-Adding `package rangeplot;` at the top of the Plot.java before compiling it.

-Adding `import Plot;` at the top of the RangePlot.java file.

The error stays exactly the same. Both files are in the same folder called rangeplot.

Comment: Could be one of approximately a hundred things.  We need to see more details to be able to tell you definitively which one it is.

Comment: Could you please provide exact error message?

Comment: So **where** have you put the Plot.java file in relation to your RangePlot.java file?

Comment: They're in the same folder if that's what you mean.

Comment: And have you compiled Plot.java first?

Comment: @Vincent Maybe the `.java` files are in the same folder, but the **`Plot.java` file does not have a `package` statement** up top, so the `Plot` class is not in the same *package* as `RangePlot`, and cannot be found by the compiler. *Solution:* Add `package` statement. --- See "[The Java™ Tutorials - Managing Source and Class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)" to learn more.

Comment: @Andreas I've tried that, but I get the exact same error.

Comment: @Vincent You tried what? Edit the question and **show us** what you've tried. Don't link to code. Show the code in the question. And remove the parts of the code that's unrelated to the question, i.e. create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE).

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, this is all a bit new for me. Is this better? I thought I'd link to the Plot source code because I'm not sure which part of it causes an issue, if any. I understand why people wouldn't want to read through all that though...

Comment: @Vincent Did you read the page I linked to in my previous comment? You need to: 1) Keep all `.java` files in the `rangeplot` folder. 2) Have `package rangeplot;` at the top of all the `.java` files. 3) Make sure the *parent* folder of `rangeplot` is in the classpath, both for compiling and for running. The easiest way to do that is to run `javac` and `java` command from the parent folder, and qualify the files, e.g. compile with `javac rangeplot/RangePlot.java` and execute with `java rangeplot.RangePlot`. Better yet, use an IDE.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much! When I started compiling from the parent folder it worked. Sorry for being so vague. I was really tired yesterday and I wasn't sure how to describe the problem since I wasn't even really sure what I was doing... I'll keep the page you linked bookmarked for whenever I need to ask another question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it:
Add this line at the beginning of `Plot.java`:

```
package rangeplot;
```

This means that `Plot` and `Rangeplot` are now in the same package and they are visible to each other.

Another way is to add `Plot.java` to any other package or newly created package. To achieve it, create new package, for example with the name `plot`, and add this line at the beginning of `Plot.java`:

```
package plot;
```

When you've chosen my second option, then you have to go back to `Rangeplot.java` and add line:

```
import plot.*;
```

If you don't do any of these steps, `Rangeplot` is in `rangeplot` package and `Plot` is in *default* package and this means `Plot` is not visible in any other package, and what's even more important - it can't be imported (using import of the files contained in *default* package is not possible - this is the reason why I suggested creating your own, new package).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to add package where you put your (something like):

```
package com.my.study;
```

on top of the code.